# 'go get' doesn't work with my own git repository

Tags: git, go

I have set up git repo on my own server and can deal with it via ssh, something like that (I use ssh key for it)

```
git clone username@myserver.com:/home/git/repo.git
```

and I have set up git daemon, so I can use it something like following

```
git clone username@myserver.com:/home/git/repo
```

I have configured local git to use ssh instead of https, so my ~/.gitconfig has following

```
[url "username@myserver.com:"]
         insteadOf = https://myserver.com
```

and following works well

```
git clone https://myserver.com/home/git/repo
```

but when I try to deal with it by 'go get'

```
go get myserver.com/home/git/repo
```

I got an error

```
go get: unrecognized import path "myserver.com/home/git/repo": https fetch: Get "https://myserver.com/home/git/repo?go-get=1": dial tcp HERE_IS_IP_ADDR:443: connect: connection refused
```

I have already tried to do something like that

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE="myserver.com/home/git/repo"
```

but it doesn't work.

I use go version go1.16.4 linux/amd64

Could somebody help with it?

Comment: try to play debugging issue with advice Brian gives here - https://github.com/golang/go/issues/37943

Comment: Thanks. But It's about GOPRIVATE variable, which I have already tried.

Comment: Can you navigate that url in your browser on https?
e.g. `curl -v https://myserver.com/home/git/repo` I assume you will see some https error.
Do you have a valid SSL certificate on that url?
If not you will not be able to reach it, as `go get` tries to reach it over https. Secondly I think it should be a public repo or you should configure some login credentials if it is only privately accessible.

Comment: I don't want use https at all. It's my server and I only set up git and want use only it there.

Answer (score 2):

When you designate your repo as an import path to go, try adding `.git` to the chunk that represents the root of the target repository :

```
go get myserver.com/home/git/repo.git

# to get a subpackage:
go get myserver.com/home/git/repo.git/sub/pkg
```

---

`go help get` has the following paragraph :

> For more about how 'go get' finds source code to
> download, see 'go help importpath'.

`go help importpath` explains, in the `Remote import paths` section :

a few hosting platforms, like `github.com` or `bitbucket.org`, are automatically handled ; for other hosting solutions :

> To declare the code location, an import path of the form
>
> repository.vcs/path
>
> specifies the given repository, ...

where `.vcs` can be one of `.git, .hg, .svn, .bzr, .fossil`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It works for me. One thing I don't like:  'import "myserver.com/home/git/repo.git" I just wanted use it, for example, as with github.com. And I thought that it's can be achieved by git and go capabilities. But anyway thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you control the server, which means you should be able to respond with [the appropriate meta tags](https://medium.com/@dayakar88/a-guide-to-solve-no-go-import-meta-tags-for-private-repositories-with-go-modules-6b9237f9c9f). That will let you use Git ssh for checkout without having to include the `.git` in the import path.

Comment: Yes, it's my own server. Thanks for good link, I have already thought about nginx.